# Trying to get a different terminal for Cinnamon on Debian 10.3

Tags: debian, terminal, console, cinnamon, konsole

I have Debian 9 at work, which comes with Konsole as a option for terminal use. I quite like Konsole, and would like to use it for my Debian 10.3 virtualbox on my home machine. However, the only two terminal options are "Multilugual Terminal" and "Thai X Terminal". I'm using Cinnamon on both my home and work machines.

Is there any way of getting Konsole or other terminal interfaces on Debian 10.3 with Cinnamon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install it. It will pull some KDE dependencies, but this should do it:

```
$ sudo apt-get install konsole
```

Comment: Boom, that's it! Thanks friend!

Comment: Glad it worked. You should mark the answer as the accepted answer.

Comment: Yep, will do. I just have to wait 5 minutes. You were simply too quick to the draw.